# Budget line graph

Tags: graphics

I just started studying economics at the university, and therefore I started using Overleaf/LaTeX when I do my assignments. I got the basic stuff, like math commands and how to structure my assignments. I now want to challenge myself and also make my graphs in Overleaf.

In my assignment, I am asked to make a budget line and show the indifference curve for perfect complements. I have done that on a whiteboard (see picture) and I now want to transfer it to Overleaf. Can someone help me with the steps I need to do that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried some code? Can you show it to us?

Comment: This may be of interest: https://sites.google.com/site/kochiuyu/Tikz "Diagrams in Economics"

Comment: Your graph it's not well proportioned, see the difference between 0-24 and 24-30 on the vertical axis.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.07,font=\scriptsize]
\tzaxes(130,50){Pop}{Bio}
\tzticks{24,120}{24,30}
\tzline[thick]"bgt"(0,30)(120,0)
\tzline[dotted](0,0)(35,35)
\tzaxesL(6,6)(60,40){$Id_1$}
\tzaxesL(12,12)(60,40){$Id_2$}
\tzaxesL(18,18)(60,40){$Id_3$}
\tzaxesL(24,24)(60,40){$Id_4$}
\tzproj*(24,24)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```